# Animated Images in ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview

[Example Images](http://www.animated-glitter-graphics.com/halloween.html)

Would implementing these into an android app as an ImageView be the same as implementing a regular image, or would problem, low performance occur since they are .GIFs?

I am aware that .PNGs are the go to image for android so is it possible to create animated .PNG images, if not what is the best practice for including animated images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, PNG's can't be animated. From bitmap formats, only GIF supports animation. Unfortunately Android doesn't support animated gifs.

Read also this: [Display Animated GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/android-display-animated-gif)

You may use AnimationDrawable to display animated set of images. However, such storing of animation frame by frame is taking much more memory than typical animated gif.

There's no easy solution for displaying animated gif on Android at present.

Comment: there's APNG, though not supported yet in most browsers: http://people.mozilla.com/~dolske/apng/demo.html