# Working with Gif Image

Tags: android, image, gif

Can we use [Gif](http://spiralforums.biz/uploads/monthly_10_2008/post-2-1222892578.gif) image in android anywhere? I've used one example for this type of image. It shows like immovable only.

How can we use as Gif(movable) image? Is this possible in Android?

Anyone guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played gif image like this...

```
public class GIFDemo extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new GIFView(this));
    }
    private static class GIFView extends View{

        Movie movie,movie1;
        InputStream is=null,is1=null;
        long moviestart;
        long moviestart1;
        public GIFView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            is=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.cartoon);
            is1=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.animated_gif);
            movie=Movie.decodeStream(is);
            movie1=Movie.decodeStream(is1);
            //BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            //opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;    // this will request the bm
           // opts.inSampleSize = 10;   
            //movie=Movie.decodeFile("C:\\cartoon.gif");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xFFCCCCCC);
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            long now=android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            System.out.println("now="+now);
             if (moviestart == 0) {   // first time
                 moviestart = now;

             }
             if(moviestart1==0)
             {
                 moviestart1=now;
             }
             System.out.println("\tmoviestart="+moviestart);
             int relTime = (int)((now - moviestart) % movie.duration()) ;
             int relTime1=(int)((now - moviestart1)% movie1.duration());
             System.out.println("time="+relTime+"\treltime="+movie.duration());
             movie.setTime(relTime);
             movie1.setTime(relTime1);
             movie.draw(canvas,10,10);
             movie1.draw(canvas,10,100);
             this.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://androidosbeginning.blogspot.com/2010/09/gif-animation-in-android.html) article. I think it helps you 
And for more info about gif animation look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/android-display-animated-gif)