# Animated Loader

Tags: android, loader, animated

I'm new to Loader. I've some examples for Android Loader. But, no one is in animated style.

How can I create an animated Loader. Like this

[image: Loader]

Anyone Guide me to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html)? because I don't think this has much to do with what you've asked for in the question.

Comment: No, i'm doing loader instead of Progress bar. So, i want to display the loader like this. Is that possible @Reno

Comment: Refer this link here.It simply plays a gif image http://stackoverflow.com/a/8321809/874752

Comment: I want to do this in Loader. How to do this @sony

Comment: So what you want is a custom Progress Dialog?

Comment: Actually i have no idea about loaders,because i didnt work api>10 .Loader class is available from level>11.But one thing i suggest that in place of progress bar you can set view(which returns from the class GIFView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show this image before initLoader and hide it on onLoadFinished

Comment: yeah this is the way to go, only if animated GIFs are rendered correctly from android.