# Using .gif file in android live wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, animated-gif

My question is regarding this post

[Is it possible to set an animated gif file as live wallpaper in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158310/is-it-possible-to-set-an-animated-gif-file-as-live-wallpaper-in-android)

The method given in this post does not seem to work. When i put my animated .gif file in /res/raw folder, there is an error which says that my file cannot be resolved or is not a field. Is there something that i should know about the resources in raw folder or there is some other problem. Following is the code.

BelleEngine() throws IOException {

```
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ballerina);
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                mBelle = Movie.decodeStream(is);
                mBelleDuration = mBelle.duration();
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Unable to open R.raw.belle");
        }
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the example it works for me. Also i have tried this with different .gif images and it doesn't seems that their is any problem. My code for that is .
{

```
 /**
     * Method to init suitable wallpaper according to time.
     */
    private void initWallpaperAccordingtoTime(InputStream inputStream) {

        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                wallpaperGifStream = Movie.decodeStream(inputStream);
                if (wallpaperGifStream != null) {
                    duration = wallpaperGifStream.duration();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

**Call to this method will be as follows.**

```
 initWallpaperAccordingtoTime(getResources().openRawResource(
             R.raw.android_apple));
```

}