# Use gif as jpg in project

Tags: android, eclipse, jpeg, gif

Can I declare a gif like a jpg in eclipse ?

```
<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/ppant"
    android:id="@+id/gifYesOrNo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
    android:src="@drawable/gif" />
```

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to declare it, but it will not move in an imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare it, but it won't be animated. If you want it to be, you can use webview (not good solution) and VideoView. You can find some help here: [Display Animated GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif). If you really want to be in a ImageView check this out: [Playing an animated GIF image file in imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428287/playing-an-animated-gif-image-file-in-imageview). Whatever you decide, you can find a lot of useful stuff here: http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/ . Hope this helps.