# How can I get the Live wallpaper selection activity to open as soon as my wallpaper services installs

Tags: android

I am using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160389/521180) to make a live wallpaper app. How can I open the live wallpaper screen automatically when my app installs?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the Android API.

Even if you find a way or a hack to achieve this, I am pretty sute this will get fixed ASAP by Google or manufacturers

There is the [`ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) Broadcast Intent, but the application being installed doesn't receive this.