# GIF is loaded successfully via glide (URL), now I want to make it live wallpaper

Tags: android, gif, android-glide

GIF is loaded successfully via glide (URL), now I want to make it live wallpaper.

( I don't want to load gif from raw folder...)

```
img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);

    Glide
            .with(this) 
            .load(gifUrl)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            //.asGif()
            .error(R.drawable.loading) // show error drawable if the image is not a gif
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(img);


    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ......................
        }
    });
}
```

Whenever gif is clicked, set as wallpaper should proceed...

Comment: Read [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158310/is-it-possible-to-set-an-animated-gif-file-as-live-wallpaper-in-android).

Comment: i want to load my gif from the internet, not from raw folder as in above link @ADM

Comment: What's happening? Are you finding some error?

Comment: yeah getting errors @statosdotcom

Comment: So post your errors from logcat or describe'em for us, please.