# gif images in android

Tags: android, animation, gif

I was studying the ApiDemos code samples and saw a sample which was animating a gif image. It was working fine. When I replaced that gif image i.e. R.drawable.animated_gif with my own gif image, it squashes/distorted the gif image and was not working properly. Any idea?
Here is the onDraw() method of MyView class:

```
@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xFFCCCCCC);                           
            long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            if (mMovieStart == 0) {
                mMovieStart = now;
            }
            if (mMovie != null) {

                int dur = Math.max(mMovie.duration(), 1);
                int pos = (int)(now % dur);
                mMovie.setTime(pos);
                mMovie.draw(canvas, getWidth() - mMovie.width(),
                            getHeight() - mMovie.height());
                invalidate();
            }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/android-display-animated-gif See if this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Since you've proved no code, it's hard to help, however, have you tried:

```
android:scaledType="centerInside"
```

or

```
android:scaledType="centerCrop"
```

These attributes inside your ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

Check your second gif name. You shouldn't have spaces and -,+... I have the same problem earlier and find that the name of image was causing error

Comment: I am using the following to get image from resources; is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.skeleton); mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is); animation is distorted.

Comment: what is the name of gif image in drawable folder? and one think more, do you change something in your code?

Comment: Yes I made changes in the code but both the original ApiDemos and modified code results in same animation distortion.