# Is it possible to show multiple progress dialogs on ImageVIews in ListView rows

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, imageview, progressdialog

I have a ListView in which, each row of the list has an ImageView and two TextViews. First I show a default image on each row, and when I get the images (which I'm getting from internet calling an url using AsyncTasks), I replace them with the default image on the corresponding row in the ListView. 
Now I want to show a progress dialog instead of the default image on each row, and when I get an image, I will replace that progress dialog with the corresponding image.
But I'm not able to show the progress dialog on the ImageView on the rows of list view. I think the problem is that, to show Progress Dialog, it needs Context, I'm trying to pass View of the image. For 1 month now, I'm struggling with no success. So now I'm thinking, is it even possible to do that and if yes - how? Or is there any other widget I can use instead of ImageView to show Progress Dialog on it? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It can be a quick difficult for you to set in every row one progressbar. This way can reduce the performance of you app. The best way is to have a general progressbar for all rows. You can set your progressbar visibility so that it can wait for all images to be loaded bevor switching on "gone"

Comment: @Festado : Thanks for your reply. And Yes, that can be 1 solution, but not here, because the client want to show Progress Dialog on each image and replace that with image as soon as i get the image. By the way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a quick difficult for you to set in every row one progressbar. This way can reduce the performance of your app. The best way is to have a general progressbar for all rows. You can set your progressbar visibility so that it can wait for all images to be loaded bevor switching on "gone"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And Yes, that can be 1 solution, but not here, because the client want to show Progress Dialog on each image and replace that with image as soon as i get the image. By the way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution. Displaying multiple progress dialogs is not a good solution in this case.
Instead of displaying a static image when loading the view, immediately display a progress/loading animation. For example a gif [Here you can find reference how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/android-display-animated-gif). Here is an example gif file which seems suitable: http://peacechild.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/loading.gif

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though it's not the expected answer, but still its a solution. So thanks