# Android animation formats? Methods?

Tags: android, animation

Hi I'm getting some custom graphics done by a designer for an app. I'd like an animated splash screen. What file format can it be done in? I've done nothing with animation before, what is the best way? Make a gif and use a web view?

What format can an animation be in, the designer wants to know what to give to me. File type etc

Comment: This post may be useful for you; [Android - Display Animated gif](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/android-display-animated-gif)

Comment: if it is not supported what format/file types do I ask for the graphics in?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App) for the animated splash screen. 
This tutorial will provide a guide line to create animated splash screen.

I hope it will help you.

**EDITED:**

Android Supported Media Formats [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: Thanks I will use that when i am coding,for now I just need to know what kind of images the designer has to supply me, formats etc.

Comment: You check this link if you want to know the support format for images http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html, You can also check my answer i have updated it . Thanks

Comment: thanks for that, ill have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html

Or use imageview to show animation in gif format.

Comment: did you tried the gif animation thing ?