# Is it possible to set an animated gif file as background of my app in android?

Tags: android, background, animated-gif

I am doing app for Jewellery shop

I want to set a gif image as background of my app.

Is it possible to set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set the gif image but this will not animate your gif image. You need to explicitly extract the gif image into all frame and then using  animate you image as gif here is the example of

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/framelayout1"
        android:duration="1000"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/framelayout2"
        android:duration="1000"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/framelayout3"
        android:duration="1000"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/framelayout4"
        android:duration="1000"/>

    ....

</animation-list>
```

Comment: This is not entirely true, as the StackOverflow answer given below demonstartes.

Answer (score 0):

Why should this be different from using animated Gifs anywhere else on Android?
The answer is - it's exactly the same.

Here is how to display animated gifs on Android:
[Display Animated GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/android-display-animated-gif)