# Android automatically scrolling background for large image

Tags: android, background, imageview

I would like to create a background which contains large (very wide) image which keeps on scrolling in an infinite loop.

So basically, each time, only a rectangle of the image (cropped) is shown and that rectangle keeps on scrolling smoothly on top of the image in turn showing a different part of the image.

How do I do that?

Comment: for infinite scrolling you have to keep expanding your View and for smooth scrolling recycling of the views should be done. I am referring to either recycler view or List View set their background with parts of images and keep taking  the image from your asset folder or maybe network.

Comment: are you asking something like this ? https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ae128e94f2428ba494f5946392500bbf14c93a2e/687474703a2f2f73686172652e676966796f75747562652e636f6d2f79584f3431572e676966

Comment: What penta suggested was what I ended up using - the KenBurns view and the library can be found here: https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the .gif image file in the background:
[Is it possible to set an animated gif file as background of my app in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762990/is-it-possible-to-set-an-animated-gif-file-as-background-of-my-app-in-android)

**OR**

You can implement [Parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax) by yourself