# how to show gif image as a background in relative layout

Tags: android, animation, view, gif

i have an animated gif image which i want to show as a background of relative layout. I used an activity extended by view and used movie class for that but it did not solve my problem. pls any suggetion will be appriciated.

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:components="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.YourPakageName"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.example.YourPakageName.GIFView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
components:src="@drawable/congratulations" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762990/is-it-possible-to-set-an-animated-gif-file-as-background-of-my-app-in-android

Answer (score 2):

you can use Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(imageUrl)
.asGif()
.placeholder(R.drawable.loading2)
.crossFade()
.into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't support gif.
You can use some image loader plugin like [Glide](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJztDBzOLJAhWEW44KHWlUAmoQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fbumptech%2Fglide&usg=AFQjCNHZ_1a6kVBhhXyyVxpVvJaRrbqnZQ&sig2=t8m7gaq49t6DqCOb0KEvLg) or [Picasso](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjdwafSzOLJAhXPVY4KHR5yBNsQFggrMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsquare.github.io%2Fpicasso%2F&usg=AFQjCNHtRDFJvt8HPDMbENo3RvpkdPZYsA&sig2=5NT5dcMokG_jmE0U9tv0RA&bvm=bv.110151844,d.c2E) for these purposes. You have to keep the gif in the assets folder, or in a server then.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code if you want to put the button above the GIF playing.
under RelativeLayout place first ImageView with                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 and then another ImageView or Button as per your requirement . the last one show above the GIF. and then use Glide Library to show .

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_music_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="180dp"

            >

     -       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewGifPlaying"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
             android:src="@drawable/ray_music_icon"
                 />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_play"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/play_round_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>

Glide.with(this)
    .load(R.drawable.stream_animation)
    .asGif()
    .into(imageViewGifPlaying);
```