# flash animation adding to android application

Tags: java, android, flash, animation

we are developing a android application which is relevant to mobile English learning application for that application we need to add some audios videos images and animation .the all animations are in flash  styles and but we do not know how to add a flash animations to android application please if someone know about that help us

it was in macromedia 8 flash animation

Comment: try adding it in [WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19171780/2591002)

Answer (score 1):

step 1: put .swf file in assests folder 
step 2:

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
ws.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadUrl(SWF FilePath);
```

duplicate link

[How to insert a swf animation (flash) in Java for Android (Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169867/how-to-insert-a-swf-animation-flash-in-java-for-android-eclipse)