# How can I set a gif as background in android

Tags: android, image, gif

I want to set a gif for my background but I don't know how to do it. Please to help me clearly.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example with the gif animation. The view is extended to ImageView so it is not a style but you can sort it out with a RelativeLayout.

https://github.com/frapontillo/ImageViewEx