# Splashscreen with .gif image in android

Tags: android, gif, splash-screen

i am trying to create android splash screen which has gif image to be displayed but android doesn't support gif image so well so i am confused which one to use for gif image whether to use Movie or webview... can anyone suggest me a better website with good example..

thanks

Comment: May be this link can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif

Comment: Android **DOES** support GIFs (both static and animated).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/anim5.gif");
```

Please use webview for .gif file

[Demo](http://www.mediafire.com/?01ji789xqs5c2zj)

Comment: This must be a comment.

Comment: Comment but nice answer..+1 for this

Comment: Now it's perfect, looks better. +1 for updating your answer.