# Is there possible to use GIF image as drawable in Android?

Tags: android, gif, android-drawable

As i have seen some library on github https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

but for implementing this is too hactic for like me freshers.

Is there any possible way to use gif image in android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display Animated GIF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif)

Comment: @Rperryng Thanks but i have done in that way with using Animation drawable it's using frame and i am having frames more in count then it's giving freg crash problem for grow heap memory.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is an another way to implement gif format on Android.
Check that page for which formats are supported by Android platform.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

If you want to use another library like that on github link(import library issue) check that

http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/11/integrating-an-external-library-in-an-android-module/

Comment: your links are for actionbarsherlock implementation dear.