# Android 2.3.6 + Cordova GIF image not Animate

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, gif

I am making a simple Android application using Jquery Mobile in cordova version **3.6.3**. At the time of debugging the GIF image doesn't support on android platform **2.3.6**, but perfectly working on android platform **4.0**+.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7772170/1771795

Comment: if your gif image is inside the asset folder and is displayed in your JQM webpage it will work fine on android 2.3+