# Why i can not play gif animation in android videoView?

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android and want to play gif animation in android video view so my gif file in this image show:
[image]

and write this code for play that:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        videoView.setVideoPath("raw/newline.gif");
        videoView.start();
```

but when run that app,i get error,can not play this video,why?

Comment: Did you get this to work? - can a VideoView play an animated gif?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Uri uri= Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.newline);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.start();
```

Your mistake is that you can't just specify a path to resource file. In this case you have to use `Uri`.

But AFAIK `VideoView` can't play gif. So check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712090/how-to-play-animated-gif-image-from-url-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494413/play-downloaded-gif-image-in-android) solutions.