# How to display a GIF in a Service?

Tags: android, service, animated-gif, facebook-messenger

I'm building an app similar to Facebook Messenger on Android and I would like to display a GIF as the chat head/bubble. I know the chat head operates as a service and found a way to display GIFs on activities (http://android-er.blogspot.ca/2014/03/play-animated-gif-with.html), but can't get it to work for a service.

Separate, but likely related issue: I'd also like to display GIFs in the popup window (after the chat head is opened).

Answer (score 2):

Android actually can decode and display animated GIFs, using android.graphics.Movie class.

This is not too much documented, but is in [SDK Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html). Moreover, it is used in [Samples in ApiDemos in BitmapDecode example with some animated flag](https://code.google.com/p/apidemos/source/browse/trunk/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/BitmapDecode.java#103).

Find here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7772170/3626214

Comment: but with this solution you have to turn of hardware acceleration which makes the app laggy when using something like view pager.