# Custom animations in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

How would I make animations like [this](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/155726099590160993/) and [this](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/161496336613120485/)? I couldn't find any result on Google showing me how to do it. I have absolutely no idea of how to go about making such animations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation in the links implemented with animated gifs/jpegs. In order to make such animations in Android you will have to:

1. Create individual frames of your animations and save them in .png files
2. Create [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) and add your frames there
3. Use your new drawable where you'd like to see an animation

**Edit:** different way was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif)