# How to play flash files or swf files in android loading from internal storage or assets folder.?

Tags: android, flash, internal-storage

I want to create an android application that consists of flash animation which was present at the internal storage of android device.Is it possible to load the flash file from internal storage or assets folder.Can anyone help me how to play the flash file in android device loading from the internal memory.?Big thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash doesn't really exist on Android.  Adobe pulled the Flash app years ago.  Its not built into Android.  You may be able to install it still if you can find the several years old app from an independent source (it isn't on the Play store), but you'll only be able to run on 1 or 2 percent of phones.  Maybe even less than that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply dude.Its not a problem how many devices that runs on flash.But its my requirement to play flash files in android device.Is there any way to load flash files in our activity in android@Gabe Sechan

Comment: No.  Flash doesn't run on ANdroid unless you have a special player that was taken off the play store more than 2 years ago.  It basically can't be done.  And if you only care about your "requirement" and not whether your requirements make logical sense and are best for your employer, you're a poor developer.

Comment: I am new to android dude.Is there is a way to play gif images  in android

Comment: To some degree.  Static gifs aren't really supported, animated are, but the methods are pretty undocumented.  Most people go with 3rd party libraries for decoders.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif

Comment: Thanks for replying patiently dude and thanks for your valuable information about flash in android.It helps me