# How to display an animated gif image in android with click functionality?

Tags: android, webview, animated-gif

Is there any way to show the animated gif image in any control that should also display normal jpg,png formats, The image source i will get from the server.

I have tried with the Webview but i have a problem of scrolling, The image should fit to the size of the control and also it should accept the click functionality.

My Code with webview:

**Webview class:**

```
public class GIFView extends WebView {
public static final String HTML_FORMAT = "<html><body style=\"text-align: center;  vertical-align: right;background-color: transparent;\"><img src = \"%s\" /></body></html>";
public GIFView(Context context, String fileUrl) throws IOException {
    super(context);
    final String html = String.format(HTML_FORMAT, fileUrl);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
   }
}
```

**MyActivity:**

```
LinearLayout llProgress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_progress);
    GIFView gif = null;
    try {
        gif = new GIFView(this, "file:///android_asset/giphy.gif");
        llProgress.addView(gif);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can any one help me to get out of this issue please, Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView may helpful

Comment: @Krrish,There are many question related to this topics try find solution from it instead post same question again n again.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif

Comment: I achieved this by using Glide library. For further reference, please check on this link [https://github.com/bumptech/glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)