# drawable animation not workin

Tags: java, android, listview, animationdrawable

i want to use of animation drawable in my list but when i start the listActivity it crashs
 i have learned from [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)
, when i remove this 2 animation codes

```
 AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) GamePic.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();
```

,it works animated by itself in my phone (p7 with android 4.4 ) but in other phones i have tried (asus memopad 7 , sony c ) it works with no animated drawables ! attent when i use of this up codes all phones just crashes 
below is my compelet code , what is wrong ?

```
public class MyList extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.games_list);

    setListAdapter(new AA());
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(MyList.this, "item" + position + "is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


class AA extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public AA() {
        super(MyList.this, R.layout.games_list_layout, Resources2.GameListArray);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.games_list_layout, parent, false);
        }
        TextView GameName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ImageView GamePic = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView Cartridge = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        GameName.setText(Resources2.GameListArray[position]);
        GamePic.setImageResource(Resources2.GamePicArray[position]);
        Cartridge.setImageResource(Resources2.CartridgeFrame[Resources2.cartridgeColor[position]]);

        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) GamePic.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();

        return row;

    }
}

}
```

thanks

Comment: can you post screenshot, what you actually want?

Comment: animatedDrawable is like .GIF images , i want it's performance but in most status i see like JPG performance about pics in my listview

Comment: if you are using GIF images then Go through Movie Class,

Comment: im not using gif images and android does not support them easly if u have some learning links give me plz

Comment: added answer, if you want to use GIF with Movie class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found my problem !

i had used
    GamePic.setImageResource(Resources2.GamePicArray[position]);

but i should use

```
GamePic.setBackgroundResource(Resources2.GamePicArray[position]);
```

now it works fine !

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) describes, you should wait until the View is attached to the window before starting animation. Therefor, you should add an OnAttachStateChangeListener to the view that will execute when it has been attached, and start the animation from there.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image);
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim);
img.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new  View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
  AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) v.getBackground();
  animation .start();
  }

@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
}
});
```

OR Use Movie Class if You are using GIF. here are some Learning Links, [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/03/play-animated-gif-with.html) , [this](http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/) and [this](http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/07/android-and-how-to-use-animated-gifs/) also [this quistion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif)

Comment: i have 181 drawable animation xml and i can't convert +400 pics to gif

Comment: hum what do you actually implementing. are you using it in listview?

Comment: edited answer. try this suggestion. i read your question but actually i meant to know if you have any alternatives,