# Playing an animated GIF image file in an imageview

Tags: android

The problem is I am using an animated gif image file, so when I added this gif image to an image view, it's only displaying an static image and not doing the animations.

Here is the code:

```
public class Animationscreen  extends AppCompatActivity {


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.animtion);

   final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imganim);

   final Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),R.anim.rotate);

    final Animation an2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),R.anim.abc_fade_out);

//final Context context = null;

    iv.startAnimation(an);

    an.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            iv.startAnimation(an2);

            finish();

            Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(), Registeration.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
  }
}
```

any one can help solving this solution as I have tried other code also with using frame by frame and using video file or movie file but still the code is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Animated GIF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif)