# Showing gifs in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am using a normal image view to display images from my server, now I want to show gif animations but have no idea how to do it, can you please help me?

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif

Answer (score 4):

I use this library in my project https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

It works perfectly in RecyclerView.

Using library is very simple, just add

```
 compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.16'
```

to your **build.gradle** file
and use it in you layout like this

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/src_anim"
android:background="@drawable/bg_anim"
/>
```

Or you can use it from code like this:

```
GifDrawable gifFromPath = new GifDrawable( "/path/anim.gif" );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library called Glide, check this link
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Add the dependency to your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

To show the gif in your ImageView use this sample:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .asGif()
    .crossFade()
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: @user3693698 then you should get used to it, since otherwise you will need to code everything yourself.