# RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000 using MediaMetaDataRetreiver

Tags: android, gif, runtimeexception, mediametadataretriever

I am trying to make a gif app on android. The gifs are made and saved in ExternalStoragePublicDirectory. Now I am trying to get those files and show it in a recyclerview using MediaMetadataReteiver by passing the files to the adapter. Below is the code in the onBindViewHolder().

```
Log.d("GifAdapter: ", files[position].getAbsolutePath());
try {
retriever.setDataSource(files[position].getAbsolutePath());
holder.mImageView.setImageBitmap(retriever.getFrameAtTime(1000000, OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC));
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It gives me RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000.
I tried using a different directory containing video files. It worked and i got the frames to display. But when i use it with gifs it gives me runtime exception. What should i do to get the gifs displayed. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use an image library like glide or something? Check this link, might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48971859/4978133

Comment: @ClintPaul Thankyou for your reply i used it, and gifs are displayed too, but now i am getting out of memory exception, though the app isn't crashing. it would have been great if i was to show only the thumbnails.

Comment: 'GlideApp  
    .with(context)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(gifUrl)
    .into(imageViewGifAsBitmap);'

Try this, It'll only show the first frame of the GIF.

Comment: Thanks @Clint Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Glide to show Gifs. It will handle gifs and Images for you

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Hey man thanks for your reply i used it, and gifs are displayed too, but now i am getting out of memory exception, though the app isn't crashing. it would have been great if i was to show only the thumbnails.

Comment: You cannot show the full sized images or gifs. So if the thumbnail imageview size is 100x100 and you load a 1000x1000 image in it, memory usage will be high. You need to decrease the image size so that the memory usage is low

Comment: Both the answers helped me actually thanks Sucho and Clint Paul