# How to use AnimatedImageDrawable (GIF image) before API 28?

Tags: android, gif, android-9.0-pie, animatedimagedrawable

In API 28 `AnimatedImageDrawable` was introduced for displaying gif images:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedImageDrawable.html

> Drawable for drawing animated images (like GIF).

The problem is that they don't told anything about how to use it with `AppCompat-v7` or `Support-v4` libraries for retrocompatibility before API 28.

Does anyone know if is possible to use it before API 28 for displaying GIF images?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: No, you can't use `AnimatedImageDrawable` below API 28 and there is no compat version of the class.

For your problem you have different options based on your situation:

1. If in your app you are already using `Picasso` or `Glide`, they both handle GIF images automatically and you can use them in place of AnimatedImageDrawable (I discourage you to add those big libraries just to handle GIF if you don't need the other features they provide).
2. You can use a `WebView` embedding the image in an HTML and then loading the HTML page inside the WebView
3. Use a known library to do that which is API 17+, called [Android Gif Drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable)

> For both options 1 and 2 you can find plenty of examples online. Some of them are in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif):

Answer (score 4):

Use [Android Movie](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie) class, here is an example of how to play GIF's:

```
// initialize Movie object
Movie movie = Movie.decodeStream(resources.openRawResource(R.drawable.my_gif));
int startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

// drawing GIF to Canvas
// this line will make your GIF looping
movie.setTime((int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) % movie.duration());
movie.draw(canvas, x, y);  // pass the coordinates of drawing
```