# How to have animated .gif imageview with rounded corners in Android messager

Tags: android, xmpp, open-source, messaging

I'm extremely new to programing in its entirety, and have been slowly learning by tweaking an open source messaging app. One thing I'm trying to implement is having animated .gif messages play in the chat with rounded corners, and cannot for the life of me find anything about this that works for me. I can either have rounded corners via roundedimageview but gifs don't play in the chats, or I can have gifs play in chat with the normal imageview but not have rounded corners.

I've attempted to add a cardview to get the result I'm after, however every example I find on how to add it results in the app crashing whn loading media files.

The source code can he found here: https://codeberg.org/RogueRen/cheogram-android-modern

And the file controling the images I'm wanting to work on are in src/main/layout/message_content.xml

Attempted: Rouded image view, standard image view, card view, card view containing an image view

Comment: Wrong path, path is src/main/res/layout/message_content.xml

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While new you should ideally search for existing Android solutions to your problem and attempt to solve it yourself. Example search: "site: stackoverflow.com android animated gif" gives me: [Display Animated GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3660209/295004) which based on last updated gives a number of possible solutions.

Comment: I spent 7 hours looking for solutions and this somehow escaped me

Comment: Did [Display Animated GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3660209/295004) answer your question?  If not, might you please [edit] your question to reproduce your *app crashing whn loading media files.* within the question itself?  As explained in [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/3744182) it's helpful for us, when answering your question, to see your problem in the question itself, not in some external link that may not always be accessible.

Comment: I'm going through the options to see if they work, so far all have failed but I haven't determined why yet

Comment: No, none of the thing listed in that linked post have worked